# Rails 3 Tinymce css style error: Failed to load source

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, tinymce

I have chosen advanced mode in tiny mce.
But in my view I see this:
[image]

Which is not the advanced theme of tiny mce.

I have looked in the html for the page and found this with firebug:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" _mce_href="http://localhost:3000/javascripts/tiny_mce/themes/simple/skins/default/content.css?1303749502" href="http://localhost:3000/javascripts/tiny_mce/themes/simple/skins/default/content.css?1303749502">
Failed to load source for: http://localhost:3000/javascripts/tiny_mce/themes/simple/skins/default/content.css?1303749502
```

I have followed this guide to install tiny mce: 
https://github.com/kete/tiny_mce

Why does it failed to load the source? 
Do I need to add something to my route file?

Comment: Routing error: No route matches "/javascripts/tiny_mce/themes/simple/skins/default/content.%C2%ADcss" I just dont know how I should create the route

Comment: Yes I can view the css on this url: http://localhost:3000/javascripts/tiny_mce/themes/simple/skins/default/content.css

Comment: I have the solution. I removed my class from the text field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed my class from the text field